# CSS Google map disappear effect

Tags: css, google-maps

How I can get disappear effect on google map with css like image?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
.my-blurred-element {
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 8px white inset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @RUL's answer. Although, I'd add an SVG layer on top as a mask, to stop the event bubbling and map interaction on the white area.

You can stop propagation by capturing the click event on the SVG mask:

```
$('.svg-mask').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

The above example uses jQuery for the event listener.